# I have a question about proof of Residue at a simple pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm studying complex analysis with *Complex Variables with Applications* by Silverman & Ponnusmamy.

There's a theorem about residue.

"Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be analytic at $z_0$. If $g(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ and $f(z_0) \neq 0$. Then, we have

Res[$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$; $z_0$]= $\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$ and Res[$\frac{1}{g(z)}$; $z_0$]= $\frac{1}{g'(z_0)}$. "

but in the proof of this theorem, i can't understand "By hypothesis, $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ has a simple pole at $z_0$." it starts with this.

I can't understand how this work.

[image]

Comment: There must be something missing. As written, this is wrong. If $f(z_0) \ne 0$ and $g$ has a multiple zero at $z_0$ then $f/g$ has a multiple pole at $z_0$. Perhaps it is assumed that $g'(z_0) \ne 0$?

Comment: Sorry it's my fault! i edited it.

Comment: You probably mean “$g(z)$ has a simple **zero** at $z_0$.”

Comment: no. I double checked it out, it's simple **pole** not zero.

Comment: That makes no sense. If $g$ has a simple zero at $z_0$  and $f(z_0) \ne 0$ then $f/g$ has a simple pole at $z_0$.

Comment: As @MartinR comments, it's definitely a typo: $g$ evidently has a simple _zero_...

Comment: i just added a capture of theorem. so it's a typo and zero is right?

Comment: Yes. Everything else makes no sense. Note also that $g$ is assumed to be *analytic* at $z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

The authors write that:

> A function $f(z)$, analytic in a deleted neighborhood of $z=z_0$, has a pole of order $k$ ($k$ a positive integer) if$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(z)=A\ne0,\infty.$$

In particular, $f$ has a simple pole if$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=A\ne0,\infty.$$But\begin{align}\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}}\\&=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}\ne0,\infty.\end{align}